# Elastic Search: How to extend standard analyzer for Query String Search

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

I'm trying to create a custom analyzer for a query string search. I want this to be exactly the same as the standard analyzer, but with the inclusion of a synonym list.

I do not want this analyzer to be used during indexing or search time on the fields themselves, only on the query string query.

I've been able to define an analyzer at index time, but I'm unsure of the exact settings for the standard analyzer. On top of that, I can't seem to prevent indexing using this analyzer. How can this be fixed?

Comment: can I just ask, why don't you want synonyms applying at index time? if you wanted them applying at index time this would be much simpler and you'd just follow http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html and in the option where it says `"filter" : ["synonym"]` you'd just do `"filter" : ["synonym","standard"]` instead.

Comment: 1) The standard analyzer uses more than the standard token filter. I know at least that. I don't know which specific token filters are used or with what settings though.

2) I attempted to use the synonym analyzer at index time. It caused a significant decrease in accuracy. When I tried at query time, it improved accuracy which was the whole point.

3) I want to be able to selectively apply synonyms. If done at index time, those tokens will always be interpreted as their synonyms. If done at search time, I have the option to apply the synonyms or not based on other information available.